# Prevent Ctrl+C from interrupting exec.Command in Golang

Tags: multithreading, go, subprocess, goroutine, sigint

I've noticed that processes started with `exec.Command` get interrupted even when the interrupt call has been intercepted via `signal.Notify`. I've done the following example to show the issue:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func sleep() {
    log.Println("Sleep start")
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "60")
    cmd.Run()
    log.Println("Sleep stop")
}

func main() {
    var doneChannel = make(chan bool)

    go sleep()

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-c
        log.Println("Receved Ctrl + C")
    }()

    <-doneChannel
}
```

If Ctrl+C is pressed while this program is running, it's going to print:

```
2015/10/16 10:05:50 Sleep start
^C2015/10/16 10:05:52 Receved Ctrl + C
2015/10/16 10:05:52 Sleep stop
```

showing that the `sleep` commands gets interrupted. Ctrl+C is successfully caught though and the main program doesn't quit, it's just the `sleep` commands that gets affected.

Any idea how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shell will signal the entire process group when you press `ctrl+c`. If you signal the parent process directly, the child process won't receive the signal.

To prevent the shell from signaling the children, you need to start the command in its own process group with with the `Setpgid` and `Pgid` fields in [`syscall.SysProcAttr`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SysProcAttr) before starting the processes

```
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "60")
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Setpgid: true,
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for windows as there is no `Setpgid` in `SysProcAttr` under windows. Any alternatives?

Comment: @tkausl Yes. On Windows you need to set `CreationFlags` in the `syscall.SysProcAttr` to `syscall.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`.

Answer (score -2):

You can ignore the `syscall.SIGINT` signal, then it won't be passed to the `exec.Command`.

```
func main() {
    var doneChannel = make(chan bool)

    signal.Ignore(syscall.SIGINT)

    go func() {
        log.Println("Sleep start")
        cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "10")
        cmd.Run()
        log.Println("Sleep stop")
        doneChannel <- true
    }()

    <-doneChannel
}
```

Comment: import("os/signal"
"syscall")

Comment: This only works because the child (in this case `sleep`) inherits parent's signal dispositions. The signal is still delivered and this might fail if the target application restores default signal behavior with e.g. `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)` or sets it's own signal handler.