# Ignore signals in cmd.Run

Tags: go

I want the CTRL C to be ignored when I run the Go program, then, I'm already managing it with the following code:

```
// Wait for all goroutines to exit before stopping
func manageCleanExit() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-c
        INTERRUPT_REQUEST = true
        runningGoroutinesChecker()
        logger.Info("Exiting")
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
}
```

But it looks like it's not catching the CTRL C when running bash commands with the following code:

```
// Run a shell command
func runShellCommand(command string) (string, string) {
    var shell_to_use string = "/usr/bin/bash"
    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer


    cmd := exec.Command(shell_to_use, "-c", command)

    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(stderr.String())
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    return stdout.String(), stderr.String()
}
```

How can I ignore the CTRL C signals in my function above ?

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: The _what_? `stdin`? Are you talking about `SIGINT`?

Comment: Stdin is the std input file descriptor, ctrl-c sends a SIGINT signal; these are not related.

Comment: You are both right, I'm sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: Your shell is probably sending the SIGINT to the entire process group. (also, your notify channel is not correctly buffered, so you may miss the signal entirely)

Comment: @JimB's diagnosis is correct. This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33165530/1256452).

Comment: @torek yes it's working. Sorry for taking your time.